# Hit another url from observers in Magento

Tags: magento, events, url, post, curl

Hi i have a multi site on our server  one is in magento and other is in core .
I have develop a module through which the user will create automatically to another site whn he signups to magento site.
It works fine . Basivally i need to post data on the another site url to make it happens .

Now i want to hit the another url to make it logout . I have use the magento event

this is my config file

```
<customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <Jamesckemp_Singlesignon_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Jamesckemp_Singlesignon_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>CustomerLogout</method>
                </Jamesckemp_Singlesignon_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>
```

and in my observer

`public function CustomerLogout($observer) {

    }`

> in this like for eg i need to hit the url like
>   http://example.com/logout

but i cant understand how to hit that .

> Can i hit through curl or some other method

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have found the solution

```
    public function CustomerLogout($observer) {


echo "<form action='https://example.com/logout' method='post' name='logoutt'>";
echo "<input style='visibility: hidden;' type='submit'  name='Submit'>";

            echo "</form>
            <script language=\"JavaScript\">
            document.logoutt.submit();
            </script>";

    }
```